# Is Perl's -w switch for warnings deprecated after 5.6.x?

Tags: perl

I read in Simon Cozens' book "Beginning Perl" that -w switch for warnings would be deprecated going forward. Is this true or is it still ok to continue using -w rather than "use warnings".

Comment: Upgrade your Perl tutorial book to something written much more recently. That book is ancient history. :)

Comment: I have narrowed down to a few books by popularity - 1) Learning Perl 2) Programming Perl and 3) Perl Cookbook. I am planning to use these 3 for now. Will appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: use strict;
use warning;

I feel use warnings,strict are the most elegant way of perl programming.

Comment: I have that firmly in my mind now. Will realise their importance as I code more.

Comment: @Wilderness: do a search on this site in the `[books]] [perl]` tags. There are several excellent books out in the last year or so, e.g. *Effective Perl Programming*, *Mastering Perl* and *Modern Perl Progamming*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The perlrun documentation (see `perldoc perlrun` or [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)) indicates that the -w option is still available as of Perl 5.12.2.  Using the pragma gets you nifty benefits though, like [turning warnings on lexically](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html) and finer grained warnings.

[Here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html#What's-wrong-with-*-w*-and-%24%5eW) is a blurb on why you should use the pragma instead of the command line option.

Comment: Thanks, mfollett ! I get your point. So, I should make a habit of using:

#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warning;

instead of:

#!/usr/local/bin -w

?

Comment: When using -w, does running the script as   perl foo.pl   turn warnings on?

Comment: @Wilderness: `use warnings;` should not be on the shebang line. It's a normal Perl statement.

Comment: @tsee: SOF removes white spaces. I do use it as another statement. I understand that, by your answer below, "#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w" inside the script will turn warnings on globally even if it is not command line? Or does the interpreter convert the shebang line into a command line automatically for running perl?

Comment: @Wilderness: Essentially, yes. It's *almost* the same.

Answer (score 4):

The -w option will **NOT** go away!

The preferred method of turning on warnings is `use warnings` because -w has a global effect. (In fact, -w is implemented by means of a global variable `$^W`. That alone should tell you that the lexical version is safer.)